# Android pixel RPG where, around the midpoint, it's revealed that the world is a simulation for survivors of some disaster

Tags: story-identification, video-games, rpg

I think I played this around 2010 as a free RPG, possibly via Amazon Gaming (they frequently offered free games, and I went through a rash of "buying" each just to have it in my library). The gameplay was a fairly generic fantasy RPG style reminiscent of the early *Final Fantasy* games. The detail which is sticking out in my mind is that at some point, I think only around the midpoint of the game, the protagonist finishes a dungeon, maybe touches some sort of rune, and is informed of the true nature of the world he lives in. Some disaster happened, and the survivors were put into a simulation until the world could be made safe for them. Something went wrong, and the people have been trapped in this fantasy world for a long amount of time, unaware of the real world. The protagonist was either someone who had root access, or was a program himself, but they were the key to freeing humanity from the simulation.

Unfortunately, I don't remember whether the character had the "wake up , time for school" opening or if they had a more established adult identity. The gameplay was somewhat more reminiscent of the *Final Fantasy Legend* Gameboy games (which I'm given to understand were actually *SaGa* games) with, I think, battles involving the characters being at the bottom of the screen with menus rather than at the side with *Final Fantasy*. I remember at the time thinking that the mechanics felt slightly half-baked with gameplay being a little too easy at first. The pixel art was about at SNES levels, and the music wasn't anything that stuck in my head. I think the protagonist was male and outwardly Caucasian, but it could be there was a choice and I just made a protagonist that looked like me.

Comment: Feels like an RPGMaker title.  I know there were a bunch as indie creations exploded, although I'm only familiar with a handful.